# Does this sequence converge and if so what is its limit.

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
\frac{4n}{n+1}\cosh(\dfrac{n\pi i}{2})
$$
I think if cosh converges then the sequence converges but I'not sure how.

Comment: cosh of an imaginary number is just cos. Then it becomes a really boring sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As orion said, from the formula for $$\cosh = \frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{2},$$ we see that $$\cosh(iz) = \frac{e^iz + e^{-iz}}{2} = \cos(z)$$
Your $\cos$ takes the arguments $\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}$, etc, which gives us 1, 0, -1, 0, etc. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4n}{n+1} = 4$, we have that your function is alternating closer and closer to values 4 and 0, so your sequence doesn't converge.

Comment: I made a correction, thank you!